# C lang: bus error occurs when I try to write 3 and more elements to an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, input, malloc

By my task I should write multi-file program that must accept int - as an array length and array elements - as a double. But something going wrong when i tried input 3 and more elements.

I know that is something to do with pointers and malloc function, but really dont't understand where is problem.

Here is my code.
Main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../data_libs/data_io.h"
#include "data_process.h"

int main() {
    double *data = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    if (input(&data, &n) == 1) {
        printf("aboa\n");
        output(data, n);
        if (normalization(data, n)) {
            output(data, n);
            free(data);
        } else
            printf("ERROR=======\n");
    } else
        printf("ERROR+++++++\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Input & output functions in data_io.c:

```
#include "data_io.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input(double **data, int *n) {
    if (scanf("%d", n) == 1) {
        printf("n is int\n");
        printf("n = %d\n", *n);
        (*data) = malloc((*n) * sizeof(double));
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%lf", data[i]) != 1)
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

void output(double *data, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == n - 1)
            printf("%lf", data[i]);
        else
            printf("%lf ", data[i]);
    }
}
```

Header file data_io.h for data_io.c

```
#ifndef DATA_IO_H
#define DATA_IO_H

int input(double **data, int *n);
void output(double *data, int n);

#endif
```

Comment: `*data` points to the allocated block of memory. `data[0]` is another way to say `*data`, so `data[1+]` doesn't work since you don't have an array of pointers. You need something like `if (scanf("%lf", &data[0][i]) != 1)`, `&(*data)[i]` also works.

Comment: Or `if (scanf("%lf", *data + i) != 1)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, that may be the least offensive.

Comment: @RetiredNinja
I don't quite understand what the problem was.

So I was originally passing a pointer to an allocated block of memory and trying to write all inputs to it? Or what?

Comment: @Re.translator You don't have an array of `double*` - you have a single `double*` pointing to an array of `double`s.

Comment: @TedLyngmo **`normalization`** function placed in other file.c :)
don't ask why, just a task i dunno.

your version of scanf seems more understandable, thanks 

Comment: @Re.translator _"**normalization** function placed in other file.c :) don't ask why"_ - Ok :-) ... and you're welcome! I added an option to the answer that may make it easier to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a pointer to a single `double*`. When you do `data[i]` you request the ***i*** th `double*` in an array of `double*`, which you don't have. You have only *one* `double*`, pointing at memory suited for `*n` `double`s, so only `data[0]` is valid to dereference.

Some alternatives to get to the ***i*** th `double` in the allocated memory:

```c
*data + i
data[0] + i
&(*data)[i]
&data[0][i]
```

If the double pointers makes it hard, you could dereference `data` with `*data`, which you know point at an array of `double`s, and assign it to a temporary variable and use that in the rest of the function. Example:

```c
*data = malloc(*n * sizeof(double));
double *tmp = *data;
for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    if (scanf("%lf", &tmp[i]) != 1) return false;
    //               ^^^^^^^
    // or just       tmp + i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
if (scanf("%lf", data[i]) != 1)
```

`scanf` requires the adress of the data, and as `data` is a reference to a pointer to the actual array, you must use `&(*data)[i]` as the parameter to `scanf()` (this will dereference the pointer, access the array element `i` and take it's address)

IMHO, you had a better approach (if you want to allocate the memory for the array in the body of the funcion) to return the pointer to the allocated array, instead of managing an extra level of indirection.  As you now return 1 or 0 to indicate success or failure, you can return the pointer to the array or `NULL` in case something went bad.